# Getting response from Mandrill using SMTPClient in vb .net

Tags: .net, email, smtp, smtpclient, mandrill

I'm sending emails to clients in a .net application using Mail.MailMessage and Mail.SmtpClient.
The host used is mandrill's SMTP, BUT i am not using their email sending API (just the SMTP server)

Is there a way to get a response(email status) from Mandrill about a sent email in code, but while using the SMTPClient and not their API?
I know this is available in the Mandrill dashboard where you can see if an email is rejected/accepted but i need this in code, after Send(mail) happens.

```
Public Sub Send()
Try
Dim mail As New System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
With mail
    .To.Add(New System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("test@test.com"))
    .CC.Add(New System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("test1@test.com"))
    .From = New System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("test2@test.com")
    .ReplyTo = New Net.Mail.MailAddress("test@test.com")
    .Subject = Me.Subject
    .Body = Me.Body
    .Attachments.Add(att)

    Dim msg As New System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient

    Dim crd As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("SMTPNetworkCredential")
    If crd Is Nothing Then
        msg.UseDefaultCredentials = True
    Else
        Dim c() As String = crd.Split(",")
        msg.UseDefaultCredentials = False
        msg.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(c(0), c(1))
    End If
    msg.Host = "smtp.mandrillapp.com"
    msg.Port = 587
    msg.Send(mail)
End With
Catch ex As Exception
Throw ex
End Try
```

End Sub

Comment: SMTP will throw exceptions for some basic failures when handing off the email to the SMTP server (invalid recipient format etc.). However, SMTP does not include any details after that. Anything done by the email server to deliver the message to the recipient is outside of the SMTP client's reach.

Comment: I handle the basic exceptions, but Mandrill includes soft/hard email bounces with a more detailed explanation, and that's what i needed. I guess i'll have to use their API, thank you :)

Comment: I believe everything is done asynchronously in Mandrill. It's likely you'll need to use webhooks to accomplish this: https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582747-Can-I-receive-bounce-notifications-via-email-